# Sum of squares of consecutive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that if the prime  $P=\frac{u^2+1}{2}$ then P is the sum of squares of two consecutive integers.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
$$u^2=2p-1$$
must be odd. Then $u$ must be odd, and hence $u=2k+1$.

This gives 
$$p=2k^2+2k+1$$
which can be written as the sum of the two consecutive perfect squares.....

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{u^2+1}2=\left(\dfrac{u-1}2\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{u+1}2\right)^2$$

Comment: $p$ isn’t necessarily prime...